# Burning DVD's in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, burning

I am having trouble getting DVD burning software to run in windows 10.

I had been using ashampoo but that no longer loads. Also tried others including Nero. Too many to list.

Has anyone got any tried and tested options for me?

Comment: I think some bug in windows 10. Once the patch upgrade release it will fix this problem.

Comment: Where does the software fail exactly?

Comment: [BurnAware says it supports W10](http://www.burnaware.com/features.html)

Comment: Burn aware does indeed. I've installed it and it works a treat :-) if you want to suggest it as an answer I can give you the credit